# File access denied in C# uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, sha256, filepicker

I am solving one issue. I am developing uwp app and I need to get sha256 hash of file selected with filepicker. 
I have complete part with filepicker, but when I select file from my computer with filepicker and I want to check hash of this file, I get error message about access denied.
Did anyone solved such a problem? I thought, that when I select file with filepicker, I can access it, right?

Comment: At least show your code where you are accessing the file. Also selecting a file just means that, you selected it, no further assertions are made like it being accessible, it being still there, and so on.

Comment: The only thing that selecting a file proves is that you had access to _read the names_ of the files contained in the directory. Nothing more.

Comment: @Nyerguds - You are not right. If you select file/s with filepicker, you get read and write permissions for selected file/s.

Comment: I have no idea what makes you think that. The only function of the filepicker is to pick a file.

Comment: @Nyerguds - from official documentation - check - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers

Comment: Interesting. The example code comments seem to indicate it, but nothing in the docs themselves actually explicitly confirms it, and the most recent user comment on the article says "if you are trying to access something out of context and don't have file permissions through UWP it just swallows the error".

Comment: @Nyerguds - It works perfectly. If you select files from computer, you can access it (read/write).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.
I problem was with init of stream, I inited a new stream by name, but it doesnt work this way.
I found, that if I go throught all files selected with filepicker, I would use object returned from filepicker.
Working example:

```
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".avi");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mpeg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mov");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mkv");

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
        if (files.Count > 0)
        {
            // doing some needed staff

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Picked files:\n\n");

            // Application now has read/write access to the picked file(s)
            foreach (StorageFile file in files)
            {
                output.Append(file.Name + "\n");

                using (IRandomAccessStream filestream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    output.Append("File SHA256 hash -> " + BytesToString(Sha256.ComputeHash(filestream.AsStreamForRead())) + "\n\n");
                    await filestream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
            this.filePickerInfo.Text = output.ToString();                
        }
        else
        {
            this.filePickerInfo.Text = "Operation cancelled.";                
        }
```